# Pourquoi la « poudrerie » est-elle disparue en France et comment y exprime-t-on cette réalité météorologique ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, origine-ou-raison, formulation-idiomatique

> [**POUDRERIE**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poudrerie), n.f. dérivé de *poudre* au sens collectif de «
>   marchandises qui se vendent en poudre » (XVe. s.) a eu le sens de «
>   poussière » (1512) ; il a pris le sens de « neige fine et sèche
>   tourbillonnant au vent » (1695), **disparu en France**, très vivant au
>   Québec où le mot se rattache à [**POUDRER**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poudrer) v. intr. « voltiger
>   dans l'air, dans le vent », le sujet désignant la neige, la pluie
>   fine. En impersonnel, *il poudre, ça poudre*.
>
> [ Dictionnaire historique de la langue française (DHLF), sup. Rey,
>   Robert, 2011, je souligne ]

Je trouve plus usuel « i(l) y a d(e) la poudrerie (dehors) » :

[image: Source de l'image : https://www.lecharlevoisien.com/2019/02/12/mercredi-jusqua-40-cm-de-neige-avec-forte-poudrerie/ (nightlife.ca)]
<sup><sup>Partie d'image provenant de [lecharlevoisien.com](https://www.lecharlevoisien.com/2019/02/12/mercredi-jusqua-40-cm-de-neige-avec-forte-poudrerie/)</sup></sup>
Une autre image :

> Certains soirs d’hiver, lorsque, dehors,
>  comme nouvellement
>   l’espace est emporté ici et là avec des ressacs
>  de branches
>   avec des rues, des abattis de poudrerie
>  puis, par moments,
>   avec de grands cratères de vide au bout du vent
>  culbuté
>   mort,
>  il fait nuit dans la neige même
>  les maisons voyagent
>   chacune pour soi
>  et j’entends dans l’intimité de la durée
>   tenant ferme les mancherons du pays sans limites
>  le vieil Ossian
>   aveugle qui chante dans les radars
>
> [ [Gaston Miron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Miron), *Le vieil Ossian*, ds. [*L'homme rapaillé*](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/lq/2002-n105-lq1188184/37317ac.pdf),
>   éd. Typo (1996), 168 ]

---

**Q.** Y a-t-il une raison particulière qui explique cette disparition, est-ce aussi le cas ailleurs dans la francophonie et brièvement pense-t-on qu'un climat changeant implique-t-il que le terme pourrait revenir... ; comment exprimerait-t-on en France ou en Belgique ou ailleurs dans la francophonie ce phénomène lorsqu'il se produit en station de sports d'hiver ou lors d'une visite au Québec ; emploierait-on typiquement le verbe *poudrer* ?

Comment: L’emploi hexagonal de ***poudrer*** : « la neige poudreuse » https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+neige+poudreuse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20neige%20poudreuse%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Pour la Belgique, je pense effectivement que le fait qu'on ait rarement ce genre de météo explique qu'on n'utilise pas vraiment ces mots. Nous n'avons pas vraiment besoin de classification: quand il neige, c'est le bazar, qu'elle soit poudreuse ou pas.

Comment: Je dirai pareil pour la France, si l'on excepte les stations de sports d'hiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

— L’emploi hexagonal de ***poudrer*** (adjectif) avec *neige* :

> La *[neige poudreuse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poudreuse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoudreuse%3B%2Cc0)*.

— ***Poudroyer***

> …, route qui *[poudroie](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poudroie&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoudroie%3B%2Cc0)* au passage d'une voiture.

---

<sup>*Complément suite aux commentaires*</sup>

Lorsqu’il y a un coup de vent quand la neige tombe, ce qui n’arrive pas tous les jours aux habitants de l’hexagone, ces derniers ne mettent pas le nez dehors ; s’ils se risquaient à sortir, on pourrait entendre :

> — La neige *poudroie*, ça rentre partout, j’en ai jusque dans le cou !

Un autre mot existe, une autre façon de *poudroyer*

— ***Voleter***

> … tandis que *[la neige volette](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voleter)* dans une succession ininterrompue de *bourrasques* derrière la fenêtre.

… dans la même veine

— ***Tourbillonner***

> … où le vent hurlait, et où *[tourbillonnaient](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tourbillonner) des rafales de neige*.

---

***P.S.***

Ce type de tempête porte un nom dans l'Ardèche, au Mont Gerbier de Jonc (*Jonc* au singulier). Elles sont redoutées, dans les mémoires des anciens il y a des personnes mortes les poumons noyés par cette neige sèche inhalée en grande quantité.

Comment: @enfernette — "La neige poudreuse" est l’état de la neige tombée, sur laquelle glissent les skis, "La neige poudroie" correspond à la photo, elle est tout à fait correcte même si peu de gens comprendraient la phrase sans explication, elle n’est pas usitée et au fond, c’est dommage :-)

Comment: D'accord, merci je comprends mieux, surtout avec _tourbillonner_. Faut croire que je suis plus très habitué à avoir la neige comme sujet d'un verbe de manière usuelle, c'est surtout _il neige/vente_ + adv./compl. ou _il y a de la poudrerie_. Le commentaire m'a fait pensé, il m'est arrivé dans cette vie de choisir un moment de tempête où il y a beaucoup de poudrerie pour aller faire une balade  au Mont-Royal avec un café (dans un thermos) etc. .. ! Nelligan est pas loin, surtout en hiver. Il suffit d'un bon manteau et d'un pantalon d'hiver au besoin*, je trouve ça particulièrement tonifiant.

Comment: * Évidemment il faut la totale, avec les gants le foulard la tuque les bottes et les lunettes de ski sont particulièrement utiles pour ne pas se faire arracher les yeux par cette neige sèche !

Answer (score 4):

A search of English's "drifting snow" led me to the *Office québécois de la langue française* entry for [*poudrerie basse*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870885), which mentions that:

> Le nom féminin
>   [chasse-neige](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chasse-neige) (TLFi via
>   CNRTL) a été adopté par l'Organisation météorologique mondiale.

CHASSE-NEIGE, subst. masc.
A.− MÉTÉOR. Vent extrêmement violent qui soulève la neige en tourbillons

[*Chasse-neige*](http://www.meteofrance.fr/publications/glossaire/149850-chasse-neige) is also found in *METEO FRANCE*'s glossary of meteorologic terms, where it's defined as:

> Le vent, lorsqu'il soulève en grande quantité de la neige au sol,
>   provoque une chasse-neige. Une telle formation de particules de neige
>   peut se maintenir à faible hauteur (chasse-neige basse), mais aussi
>   atteindre des hauteurs suffisantes pour réduire la visibilité au
>   niveau de l'œil de l'observateur (chasse-neige élevée).

*Wikipedia*'s entry for [*Poudrerie (météorologie)*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poudrerie_(m%C3%A9t%C3%A9orologie)) likewise mentions *chasse-neige* as an alternative (European) term for *poudrerie* and adds that:

> Régionalement, aux îles de Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon, le phénomène est
>   appelé [**poudrin** ou poudrin de choquette](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poudrin) (TLFi via CNRTL).

Without explaining why, that *Wikipedia* entry also seems to confirm that:

> Le terme « poudrerie » vient d'un usage qui était courant en France
>   jusqu’à la fin du xviie siècle pour désigner ce phénomène et qui se
>   perpétue au Canada.

---

Just a guess as to why *poudrerie* fell out of use in France, but perhaps by the end of the 17th century in France the consequences/importance of gunpowder and things military so outweighed the consequences/importance of snow that using the same term for both notions became to be seen as incongruous or counter-intuitive.

Likewise, for a gratuitous guess as to why *chasse-neige* has not replaced *poudrerie* in Québec [besides the fact that *poudrerie* is a perfectly relevant, beautiful, and long-established French word for the phenomenon], maybe using the same term for such indispensable tools as snow plows are in Québec and also for the very element and one of the conditions that these tools help combat would be seen as ambiguous if not just plain "wrong."

Although certainly not as dire and existential as its more obvious consequences, whether Global Climate Change could perhaps lead to a revival of the use of *poudrerie*'s second sense outside of Québec is an interesting question, and with the reasoning behind the two guesses contained in my previous two paragraphs in mind, I think that such a thing is entirely possible, especially if ever it becomes necessary to begin the July 14th parade down the Avenue des Champs-Élysée with snow plows and the parade features more of them than the mighty Leclerc: to paraphrase *Isaiah 2:4*, when tanks are turned into snow plows.

Comment: Outstanding answer; I will not change my selection but will reward your A. to make it stand out like the selected one. They have a [stamp](https://www.wnsstamps.post/fr/stamps/PM001.06.html) about it; actually the stamp doesn't seem to depict the phenomenon per se but is rather a statement about [usage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbres_de_Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon_2006#Le_poudrin_de_choquette), about language atop a seasonal image. The considerations you discuss in the last part make sense, concurrence and such. Also _chasse-neige_ is the basic move you learn in downhill skying...

Comment: The _poudrin de choquette_, well that's one for the books.  It is also an example of something discussed elsewhere in another [Q.](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40978/19187). The Termium entry contains extra [notes](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=DRIFTING+SNOW&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). I didn't know about the difference between low and high or drifting or blowing snow etc. actually in English I didn't know about the use of _drifting_ in this context. Never heard _poudrerie basse_ but it's good to know. All quite interesting,thks

Comment: @enfernette Thanks for the kind words and cool links in your two comments above! Those words alone were reward enough for me.  (That doesn't mean, however, that I'm not also very grateful for you thinking that my answer is worthy of your additional kind words and generous bounty!)

Comment: What  has drifting snow got to do with it? We say powdery snow, for the type of snow. As opposed to wet snow.